# elastic search multi-fields matching problem

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query for elastic search.
I am writing a query like this.

```
$params = [
            'index' => config('elasticsearch.index'),
            'type' => $this->type,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => 'newyork john',
                        'type'=>'cross_fields',
                        'fields'=>['user','surname','location'],
                        'tie_breaker'=>'0.3',
                        'minimum_should_match'=>'10%',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

For example, this query returns the following result.

```
id=>1
score => 0.9808292
user => nja
surname => foo
'location'=> newyork

//1 field matching

id=>2
score => 0.87546873
user => alex
surname => stephen
'location'=> newyork

//1 field matching

id=>3
score => 0.18232156,
user => alex
surname => john
'location'=> newyork

//2 field matching
```

but I want to see it at the top if there is how many more fields match.This query does not do it. Matching data for 2 field is at the bottom.I actually want to see it at the top.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to match all the fields?

Comment: yes @green if there is how much field matching.I want at top

Comment: I am confused by your answer, you wish to match all the fields or do you want to show the "best matched" at the top of your hits(i.e. in your example you want that `id=>3` would be at the top)

Comment: newyork john it has 2 fields matching.But the others only have one 'newyork' matching.So what they catch here is sorted by score number.I want to sorting with more field matching

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `most_fields` type instead of `cross_fields` :

You can see the doc here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types

> **most_fields**
>
> Finds documents which match any field and combines the _score from
>   each field. See most_fields.
>
> **cross_fields**
>
> Treats fields with the same analyzer as though they were one big
>   field. Looks for each word in any field. See cross_fields.

The `most_fields` type will add the score of the matching fields, and thus give a significant boost to documents matching the query in different fields.